# parse error in ruby routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am launching my first ruby server i have launched the server to view the welcome aboard page and have generated a controller for the page however when i change the route file and uncomment the following statement

```
  root 'welcome#index'
```

I get the following error

```
JSON::ParserError in Welcome#index
Showing C:/Sites/examplesite/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
where line #5 raised:
757: unexpected token at 'Script execution time was exceeded on script 
"AppData\Local\Temp\execjs20160617-1504-n6adzfjs".
Script execution was terminated.
'
Rails.root: C:/Sites/examplesite
```

what part of the code is causing the error and how can it be fixed

these are the code which is run

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest     priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'welcome#index'
  #root 'welcome#index'
```

application.html.erb (where the error is reported on line 5)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Examplesite</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Per the error message, it's line 5 in application.html.erb. Beyond that it's really difficult to tell since we don't have any minimal code you wrote demonstrating the problem. Read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]".

Comment: i have included all the code including the code that raised the error and the supporting code

Answer (score 1):

Is this producing on other machines too? 
This message is issued if the systems cscript timeout period is exceeded before a script completes execution.

Any program that uses the cscript command in Windows has the ability to add a /s switch in addition to the /t timeout command.

When the /s switch is used, all of the switches from the command (which includes the /t timeout) are saved to the registry.

Vivado does not use the /s switch.

However, the cscript commands that are issued from Vivado are subject to the settings saved by another program.

To fix this, go to the following location in the registry (regedit), and delete the "Timeout" key, or set it to 0:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings**